# docker build running forever, and taking infinite amount of space

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, docker-image

First I have build a Dockerfile in which I wrote the simple code :

```
FROM centos
RUN echo "first commit" > /tmp/file1
```

then for making the docker image from this Dockerfile I wrote the command :

```
docker build -t <image_name> .
```

but after hitting enter it goes forever and continuosly taking space until I forcefully stopped the command. It show

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  <space which is continuously inceasing>
```

Please help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: What directory are you in on the host when you run that command?  `docker build .` will send the entire current directory (`.`) to the Docker daemon, less whatever's excluded in a `.dockerignore` file; if that's your entire home directory it could be a lot.

Comment: I ran the command from the home directory ? Is this a problem to pulling a docker image from the home of host ? But it is working if I create a container by direct pulling form Registry not using Dockerfile.

Comment: It is sending your entire home directory to the Docker daemon, before it even starts to look at the Dockerfile.  Move this setup to a different directory.

Comment: So where this space is goes, and where Daemon move the home directory ?                                                                      
And can you tell me how to solve this problem ?                                                     Thanks

Comment: It's being sent across the Docker socket connection to the Docker daemon, and stored in temporary space owned by the daemon.  Use a subdirectory for this work and not your home directory.

Comment: Thanks, It worked, Insteed of home directory now I am running the docker commands from a empty directory.

Comment: One more quesiton, In a previous reply you wrote that "It is sending your entire home directory to the Docker daemon" so here "it" means client who is sending the directory to docker daemon ?

Comment: Yes, the `docker build .` command.